# Alternatives for DataSource and DisplayMember in WPF so I can display SQLite database content inside a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, xaml

I have asked this question before and it got flagged for not being detailed enough so I thought I would rephrase it and better detail my problem.

**Summarise the problem:**

First of all, I was following this tutorial 'Using SQLite in C# - Building Simple, Powerful, Portable Databases for Your Application' (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayp3tHEkRc0). The creator of this tutorial had this form:

[image]

In the form you could add a first name and a listname and it shows up in the List People. This was his code-behind:

[image]

I followed the tutorial and I decided I would replicate this but instead of 'Person' it will display the user's statistics:

[image]

I want to be able to display the SQLite table content inside a listbox. But the problem is that in WPF there is no such thing as 'DataSource' or 'DisplayMember'. This is my code so far:

```
public partial class databasetestform : Window
    {
        List<UserStatistics> userstatistics = new List<UserStatistics>();
        public databasetestform()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void LoadStatistics_List()
        {
            userstatistics = SQLiteDataAccess.LoadStatistics();

            WriteUpStatisticsList();
        }
        public void WriteUpStatisticsList()
        {
            // Unsure what to do here
        }

        private void Load_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadStatistics_List();
            UserStatistics s = new UserStatistics();

            int result1;
            int result2;

            if(int.TryParse(AVGtxtbox.Text, out result1))
            {
                s.GamesPlayed = result1;
                SQLiteDataAccess.SaveStatistics(s);
            }
            if (int.TryParse(AVGtxtbox.Text, out result2))
            {
                s.GamesPlayed_ScoreAverage = result2;
                SQLiteDataAccess.SaveStatistics(s);
            }



            AVGtxtbox.Text = "";
            PLYDtxtbox.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

**Describe what you've tried**

I've tried for many hours to find a work-around, I tried to use 'ItemsSource' instead of DataSource but I still had no work-around for 'DisplayMember'.

Hope I can get a solution to this.

Thanks,

Comment: WPF uses `DataContext`, give that some research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're on the right track.

`ItemsSource` is the correct property to use for your data source. It accepts any `IEnumerable` so your `List<T>` should work just fine.

Instead of `DisplayMember`, I think you're looking for [`DisplayMemberPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath). You can set this to the name of a property declared on your `UserStatistics` object and the `ListBoxItem`s will display the value of that property.

The C# would be as simple as:

```
MyListBox.ItemsSource = userstatistics;
```

`DisplayMemberPath` would usually be set on the `ListBox` tag in the XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="MyListBox" DisplayMemberPath="SomePropertyName"/>
```

---

The above gives you the simple answer, which does work, but there are a couple other concepts you should be aware of and maybe look into later on:

- In WPF, one generally tries to avoid giving a UI element an explicit name and referencing it in code. The goal behind this is to try and separate the functional components of the program from the visual interface.
  To acheive this, the visual components (declared in XAML) are usually connected to the functional code (written in C# or VB.NET) using [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview).
  This isn't a completely strict rule, however, and I've broken it on a few occasions when it made scense, or when referencing a UI element by name was just far, far easier.
- While `DisplayMemberPath` works for displaying the value of a single property, sometimes you need a more complex display of items. This can be accomplished using [data templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview) and the [`ItemTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate) property. It requires knowledge and use of data binding.

Comment: In my application I try to separate most thinking/logic from code-behind uses classes etc - I am well aware it's bad practice. MVVM is something I will look into in the future. I think MVVM seems quite overwhelming for me right now - could you recommend some tutorials for me to follow?

Comment: The problem is that I've created a large-scale application that doesn't really implement MVVM practices and I have found some situations that this does not serve me well. I have a game and this game has two mode. These two game modes look different from one another but are the same logically. Because I didn't use an MVVM pattern I do not know how to implement this without copy and pasting the code behind of the UI. The actual functionality of the game is in another class but a lot of the other stuff is in the code-behind of the UI. So I will have a look at MVVM in the future.

Comment: I am also not entirely sure what you mean by 'one generally tries to avoid giving a UI element an explicit name and referencing it in code.' I have done this quite a lot but I did think it was fine to do until now? Again, sorry for many comments I am just a little confused.

Comment: For instance Keith if I have a button, and I add an OnClick event to it; when this OnClick event is fired I want to change the content of the button. You are saying I can't just do: buttonName.Text = "String"? What would I do for this instead?

Comment: @TomJoney Personally, I don’t implement full MVVM either and haven’t fully studied it. But, I do still try to keep the two halves separate to some extent. I’ve never made a game in WPF, so I’m not sure what intricacies that would add.

Comment: @TomJoney For the button example, I would use a `Style` with `DataTrigger`s to change the button’s appearance based the the functional state of the program. Also, I tend to use commands instead of click event handlers.